# R Studio: look up a value in table(both direction V&H), then use as a variable in loop

Tags: r, loops, lookup

I am dealing with a dataset ("IndexTable") have 3 million+ observations. Please see following for the first 6 observations:

```
     Identity gender type   amount    Year    Month
1       65      F     W     31.88     1987     Jan
2       23      M     P     29.21     1985     Mar
3       45      F     W     44.70     1987     Jan
4       47      F     W     72.64     1987     Jan
5       56      M     P     28.92     1986     Jul
6       09      F     W     34.32     1990     Jan
```

and the index table ("index") from which the value will be searched (part of the table):

```
    year  average      Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
1   1950 32.84210 33.19118 33.10321 33.01572 32.89977 32.81334 32.98665 32.98665 33.10321 32.89977 32.55677 32.41595 32.24857
2   1951 30.09866 31.94615 31.64936 31.43694 30.94371 30.19568 30.09866 29.64623 29.50617 29.29854 29.09382 28.98131 28.78098
3   1952 27.56470 28.28139 28.25313 28.11271 27.67259 27.67259 27.21981 27.24604 27.40444 27.45766 27.21981 27.24604 27.06353
4   1953 26.73099 27.08945 27.01183 26.83243 26.58025 26.68055 26.53038 26.53038 26.70575 26.75628 26.75628 26.68055 26.78162
5   1954 26.25941 26.73099 26.78162 26.53038 26.43120 26.50552 26.35730 25.92244 26.08984 26.13807 26.01783 25.89871 25.75718
6   1955 25.11668 25.66369 25.66369 25.66369 25.52472 25.57087 25.04994 24.96151 25.13901 24.98356 24.72149 24.33854 24.33854
```

For each observation in "IndexTable", I would like to find the value in "index" which match the Year and Month, then use the value to multiply it's amount to get the adjusted amount.

Thanks in advance J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `dplyr` and `tidyr` package:

```
index_long <- index %>% 
  gather(Month, multiplier, Jan:Dec) %>% 
  select(-average)

left_join(IndexTable, index_long, by = c("Year" = "year", "Month" = "Month")) %>% 
  mutate(adjusted_amount = amount*multiplier)
```

First I gather the Month columns into one column with the value column multiplier. 
I drop the average column, because it doesn't need to be joined to the other table. Then by using a left join only does value with a matching year month combination will be joined to the IndexTable. 
Then finally I used the multiplier to create the new column adjusted_amount

Comment: Thanks.about the package... do you mean dplyr instead of dpylr?

Comment: Oh sorry! Yes! Sorry about the typo.